# Обработка повторного вызова функции в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

У меня есть это функция

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def get_people(message):
    if people_call:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Человек вызван, ожидайте в течении суток ")
        people_call = False
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Человек уже вызван")
```

Выводиться вот это ошибка:

```
if people_call:
   ^^^^^^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'people_call' where it is not associated with a value
"
```

Аргумент people_call не меняет свое свойства на False. Если объявить это в функции, то при каждом вызове /help, аргумент будет становиться равным значению по умолчанию.

Я хочу, что бы при повторном вызове функции, пользователю выводило `Человек уже вызван`. Я использую библиотеку telebot

Comment: А что не работает?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Аргумент people_call не меняет свое состояние на False

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `nonlocal people_call` в начале функции `get_people`.